# Как передать сообщение в WhatsApp из стороннего приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Включаю WhatsApp, открываю диалог, вызываю поверх своё приложение и хочу из него передать, например, картинку или текст в этот диалог.

Как это можно реализовать? Если речь только о тексте, то копировать вставить как-нибудь можно настроить, но копировать и вставить картинку в Android, как я понял, нельзя. Если речь идет о контакте то можно воспользоваться Vk api и получив разрешение отправлять сообщение в диалог, а вот WhatsApp вроде удалил все исходники в сети.

Еще один вариант: например, я в галерее, открыл картинку и есть функция "отправить". Нажав на неё, открываются всяческие возможности отправки, где могу выбрать WhatsApp. Как такое реализовавать? Неплохо бы, чтобы сразу выбирался WhatsApp, это думаю можно сделать, а чтобы сразу выбирался нужный диалог уже без Api не получился наверно. Есть какие соображения?

Comment: Прочитайте здесь: [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать данные в другую Activity, необходимо использовать Intent. В данном случае он будет неявный, т.к. вы не знаете имя класса WhatsApp. Т.к. WhatsApp мессенджер, значит тег `action` внутри `intent-filter` активити WhatsApp'а будет `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>`. 
**Пример Intent'а, который необходимо использовать в своем приложении:**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message"); // Вместо My message упаковываете текст, который необходимо передать
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share text")); // Share text - заголовок диалога выбора необходимого приложения
```

Более подробно можно прочитать в [документации](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

Comment: спасибо, направили куда надо. просто я в общем не изучил построение приложений и хотел сперва одну штуку реализовать, и нужны подобные подсказки. ВЫходит неявно можно обратиться к любому приложению , но не каждое может это обращение принять , потому что оно не реализовано для этого?

Comment: Верно. Но в мессенджеры в основном можно перадать текст, изображения, видео и т.д. Вот к примеру [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) Telegram'a, там как раз данные типы `intent-filter` ипользуются, а значит в него можно расшарить данные из своего приложения.